# How can I uninstall visual studio 2013 when theere is no entry in Programs and features

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am struggling to uninstall Visual studio 2013 from my computer.  The program appears in the applications list and can be started from there, similarly I have a short cut on the taskbar and again it can be started from there.  However there is no entry in Programs and Features so I cannot run Uninstall from there as there's nothing to uninstall.

Has anyone had a similar experience, and more to the point knows how to trigger a full uninstall?

Comment: Try running the installer. Often that will give you an uninstall option.

Comment: Great suggestion, it's amazing just how frustrating vs install and uninstall can get.